# In R: is there an elegant way to split data.frame row by "," and add to existing rows matching the splitted strings?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, row

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(sample_names=c("foo","bar","foo, bar"), sample_values=c(1,5,3))
df

  sample_names sample_values
1          foo             1
2          bar             5
3     foo, bar             3
```

and I want a resulting data.frame of the following shape:

```
  sample_names sample_values
1          foo             4
2          bar             8
```

Is there a elegant way to achieve this? My workaround would be to grep by "," and somehow fidly add the result to the existing rows. Since I want to apply this on multiple dataframes, I'd like to come up with an easier solution. Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` to split the column, then do a group by operation to get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate_rows(sample_names) %>% 
   group_by(sample_names) %>% 
   summarise(sample_values = sum(sample_values), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  sample_names sample_values
#  <chr>                <dbl>
#1 bar                      8
#2 foo                      4
```

---

Or with `base R` by splitting the column with `strsplit` into a `list` of `vector`s, then use `tapply` to do a group by `sum`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(df$sample_names, ",\\s+")
tapply(rep(df$sample_values, lengths(lst1)), unlist(lst1), FUN = sum)
```